# Delimit by space but ignore backslash space

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

```
5678 []
testing,\ group []
[testing []
ip\ 5.6.7.8 []
launch-wizard-1 0.0.0.0/0
456dlkjfa []
1.2.3.4 []
test 1.2.3.4/32 4.3.2.0/23 4.3.2.0/23
default 4.3.2.0/23 4.3.2.0/23
launch-wizard-2 0.0.0.0/0
launch-wizard-3 0.0.0.0/0
2.3.4.5/32 []
```

I would like to get the first column of the above but the catch is that, I need to treat `\` **(backslash space)** as a part of the column, so `awk '{print $1}'` should give me

```
5678
testing,\ group
[testing
ip\ 5.6.7.8
launch-wizard-1
456dlkjfa
1.2.3.4
test
default
launch-wizard-2
launch-wizard-3
2.3.4.5/32
```

Comment: Is \ being treated as an escape character always or is only `\ ` special?  For instance, is  `a\\ b` one field or two?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I've put in \ is for escape character, not the real data

Comment: If your data happened to contain a real backslash, how would it be represented?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Good question. Because I replaced only `[[:space:]]` with `\[[:space:]]`, the original data has \ untouched in their place. After getting the original data in the first column delimited by only spaces and not `\[[:space:]]`, I'd be replacing `\[[:space:]]` with `[[:space:]]` and I'd be left with original data back again which has \.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

with gnu awk (`gawk`) you can use some zero-length assertions like `\<` or `\>`:

```
$ echo 'a\ b c' | gawk 'BEGIN{FS="\\> +"} {print $1}'
a\ b
```

but unfortunately not the full-blown ones from `perl` or `pcre` (eg. `(?<!\\)`, `(?<=\w)`, etc):

```
$ echo 'a\ b, c' | perl -nle '@a=split /(?<!\\)\s+/, $_; print $a[0]'
a\ b,
```

Answer (score 5):

You could substitute \space with something else and back again afterwards.

```
sed 's/\\ /\\x20/g' data_file | awk '{ print $1; }' | sed 's/\\x20/\\ /g'
```

Comment: Only with sed : sed 's/\\ /\\x20/g;s/ .*//;s/\\x20/\\ /g' data_file

Comment: Or, awk, using the default SUBSEP variable value of `\034`: `awk '{gsub(/\\ /,SUBSEP,$0); val=$1; gsub(SUBSEP,"\\ ",val); print val}' file`

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
grep -Po '^(\\.|\S)*'
```

Or with ERE:

```
grep -Eo '^(\\.|[^\[:space:]])*'
```

That treats `\` as a quoting operator, for whitespace as a delimiter, but also for itself. That is, on `foo\\ bar` input, it returns `foo\\`.

Answer (score 4):

With just `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^((([^\]*\\ ){1,})?[^ ]*).*/\1/' infile
```

Or shorter:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^\]*\\ )*[^ ]*).*/\1/' infile
```

This `(([^\]*\\ ){1,})?[^ ]*` matches:

- `[^\]*\\`: anything that it's not a back-slash which ends with back-slash followed by a space (note that `\` inside character class is not required to be escaped, but outside does).
- `([^\]*\\ ){1,}`: matching above with one-or-more times of occurrences.
- `(([^\]*\\ ){1,})?`: this is optional when using `(...)?`; we could use `([^\]*\\ ){0,}` instead as well or `([^\]*\\ )*`.
- `((([^\]*\\ ){1,})?[^ ]*)`: matches above which is optional followed by anything that it's not a space and hold as group match with `\1` as its back-reference.
- `((([^\]*\\ ){1,})?[^ ]*).*`: matches above `(...)` and anything else `.*`.

then is replacement part just print the `\1` which is the output:

```
5678
testing,\ group
[testing
ip\ 5.6.7.8
launch-wizard-1
456dlkjfa
1.2.3.4
test
default
launch-wizard-2
launch-wizard-3
2.3.4.5/32
```